# Possible to exclude certain files from being overwritten in git?

Tags: git, yaml

For example I have a branch where I don't want anyone to overwrite anything in a specific folder. Let's say it is `folder-1/test.py`, now I have another folder `folder-2/run.py` I want other people to make changes in folder-2 but any changes in folder-1 will be declined. Due to my inexperience with git, I can only think of `.yaml` files but for github actions to run you would need to push it to the repo, I want the push to be declined when the said changes occur. Is there a way to achieve this, or have I misunderstood how git works?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a pre-receive hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GitHub, you cannot use a pre-receive hook as suggested by @Guildenstern. In fact, it is not possible to *reject* a push based on its content.

Your best option is:

- Limit who can push to the repository.
- Require all changes to be submitted via pull requests.
- Implement a CI workflow (e.g. using GitHub Actions) that will fail for pull requests that contain changes to those directories.

You can also provide a `pre-commit` hook that will reject local commits that makes changes to these directories, but this is only a partial solution: `pre-commit` hooks are advisory; they must be explicitly configured by developers and they can be skipped.